# Detect button click in foreign form

Tags: c#, winapi, hook

Have can I detect a button click in foreign window?
I try GetMessage but my program freeze, and I got nothing.
I already know window and button handles
It stuck in while loop

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr handle = ReturnHandle("Form1");
            IntPtr buttonHandle = ReturnHandleEx(handle, "Login");
            Console.Out.WriteLine("handle = {0}", handle.ToString("x2"));
            Console.Out.WriteLine("buttonHandle = {0}", buttonHandle.ToString("x2"));
            MSG msg;
            sbyte ret;
            while ((ret = GetMessage(out msg, buttonHandle, 0, 0)) != -1)
            {
                if (ret == -1)
                {
                    //-1 indicates an error
                }
                else
                {
                    TranslateMessage(ref msg);
                    DispatchMessage(ref msg);
                }
                Console.Out.WriteLine("msg = {0}", msg);
            }

        }

        private static IntPtr ReturnHandle(string lpWindowName)
        {
            return FindWindow(null, lpWindowName);
        }

        private static IntPtr ReturnHandleEx(IntPtr parentHandle, string windowTitle)
        {
            return FindWindowEx(parentHandle, new IntPtr(), null, windowTitle);
        }
```

Comment: show your code and specify the line where your program is stuck

Comment: @AndyT It stuck in loop where I can try recieve message

Comment: Why can't you just handle events on that other form? This code makes no sense.

Comment: @CodyGray The  window is another in appliaction.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "foreign window" and "another in application". Do you mean another window in the same application/process or a window in remote process (another application)?

Comment: @AndyT window in another application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot receive messages from a window in another process.

To do this you need to inject your code into this process. The easiest way is to use [WinAPI hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644960(v=vs.85).aspx). You need a separate DLL for this hook. When you register a hook, this DLL will be injected into all running processes. In that DLL you need to listen to window messages, filter them and send interesting ones to your application by some kind of inter-process communication (shared memory, pipes, network or something else).

Comment: Do note that you cannot write this type of a hook DLL in a managed language. The only type of hooks that are supported in a managed DLL are the ones that do not get injected—i.e., `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` and `WH_MOUSE_LL`.

Comment: No need for hooks and hacks. [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) provides all the facilities required. You simply register an automation event handler for the button's default action, and implement the code to respond to it.